# how to disable delay signed in c#.net web projects

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting these error as

Build (web): Could not load file or assembly 'PetShop.DBUtility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7987b61c51ca872' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified. The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

So i figure it out that i need to disable the delay signal of that dll which i am using in my project

i am using vsexpress10 c# edition for development

Waiting for your solution

Comment: If your project is strongly signed, it has to load only strongly signed DLLs. If the DLL you're loading is NOT strongly signed, your project can't be either. You'll either need to get the code and compile it yourself (strongly signed), get the creator to give you a strongly signed version or not strongly sign your project

Comment: Hmmmm k it is possible to unsigned the signed dll through code.Hmmm k thanks for ur support........

Comment: Which DLL? Think of it this way - Strongly signed means that you can guarantee all the code that is running was intended to be there by the developer. This means that all components must be strongly signed, otherwise one could be swapped out and the app wouldn't know. To prevent _your_ application being strongly signed, turn off signing in project properties

Comment: Hmmm k @Basic can you give me the code to turnoff signing

Comment: @Basic i am using visualstudio express 2010 edition i do not find any project properties der

Comment: What type of project is it? Right-click the project, go to properties, look for s "signing" tab on the LHS. I'm afraid I've never used the express version but according to MS Docs, it should be in the same place.

Comment: @Basic there is no signing tab in vs-express edition

Comment: It appears that the [2012 express does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms349441(v=vs.110).aspx) "As with Visual Studio, you can use Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Web to do strong name signing, connect to Team Foundation Server, debug using different web browsers, and manage NuGet packages."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For enabling delay signing following lines are used:

```
[assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("myKey.snk")]
[assembly:AssemblyDelaySignAttribute(true)]
```

setting the 2nd attribute as false will disable the delay signing.

Comment: OP's problem seems to be attempting to load an unsigned DLL into a signed website

Comment: Oh I see, turning off the verification of signature will work in this case?
You can do this by using the –Vr option with the
Strong Name tool.The following example turns off verification for an assembly called
myAssembly.dll.
Sn –Vr myAssembly.dll

Comment: @ImranBalouch ya thanks but where to run that query give some guide lines